# SimpleXml how to append an existing XML in a new created root element

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have some XML response from the server, but they don't have a root element, because of that I can't parse them with the new SimpleXML, so I need to create a root element and then add all those xml to this one created root element

```
 $res = bill_curl('GetAccounts'); //getting a list of accounts WITHOUT the <root> xml
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<root></root>"); // creating a root element
 $xml->addChild($res); // adding to the <root> childrens
```

but the problem is:

1) the `"<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->"` stays inside and the same is at the top of the document

2) got some symbols like "<", "/>" how to remove them?

**Updated:**

```
  <document>
              <answer>
            <account>12345678</account>
            <info>someinfo</info>
            </answer>
             <answer>
            <account>23456789</account>
        <info>some info</info>
           </answer>
   </document>
```

this is what i've got after string manipulation then I make:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
```

and here I get an error of start and ending tags mismatching, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly keen on the brittleness of this solution. However, it sounds like you you're integrating against a flawed API, so I would suggest some basic string manipulation to get what you want:

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testing>2</testing><test2>1</test2>';
// the above was a test string to represent the results of the below:
$str = bill_curl('GetAccounts');

// Switch the search string below with the actual doctype you're getting from the API.
// It looks to have been commented out in your question which may or may not be the case.
$str = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '', $str);
$str = '<root>'.$str.'</root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: i've tried your code, and now i've got this "Opening and ending tag mismatch: document line 1 and xml"

Comment: You need to post the XML string you're receiving from your API (minus any sensitive data of course!)

Comment: That's working for me... is there definitely nothing else going on with the rest of your code that could be causing the issue?